# Oracle DAtabase on linux

Tags: windows, linux, oracle

I have a question about case sensitivity on oracle. I am working on a project that accesses oracle 11g database, the Oracle server is installed on windows server 2008. We are deploying this application on a linux environment at that point the application will communicate with oracle database on linux machine.

I want to know if case sensitivity will be an issue? ex. if my app queries a table name "Foo" as "select * from foo", this is not a problem in windows environment, will this be a problem in linux ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, in the sense you are talking about Oracle can be treated as case insensitive.  However, that isn't actually the case.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm):

> Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them
>   as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive

What this means is that typically all objects are created uppercase and Oracle treats:

```
select * from foo;
```

the same as:

```
select * from "FOO";
```

However, if your table was actually created as case sensitive, then you have to specify the correct case:

```
select * from "Foo";
```

It is rare in practice that you would create your objects as case sensitive, but Oracle does allow for it.  If this isn't clear, let me know and I will try to give a better explanation